# LightSwitch - Get updated rows in Search Screen

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a search screen which lists all customers. User can edit a few fields (Phone number, address, etc.).

On saving of that "particular" record (only the changed ones), I want to update the `ModifiedBy` and `ModifiedOn` fields. How can I do so in code?

I am trying to handle this in the `_Saving` event of Search Screen but how do I get the changed rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the table's Entity Designer and click the arrow next to Write Code. You'll need to edit two methods, `_Updating` and `_Inserting`. Similar to this:

**C#:**

```
partial void TableName_Updating(TableName entity)
{
    entity.ModifiedBy = this.Application.User.FullName;
    entity.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
}

partial void TableName_Inserting(TableName entity)
{
    entity.ModifiedBy = this.Application.User.FullName;
    entity.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
}
```

**VB.NET:**

```
Private Partial Sub TableName_Updating(entity As TableName)
    entity.ModifiedBy = Me.Application.User.FullName
    entity.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now
End Sub

Private Partial Sub TableName_Inserting(entity As TableName)
    entity.ModifiedBy = Me.Application.User.FullName
    entity.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this one worked and was easy. I was trying to do it at a screen level and this would need writing the same code for each screen where this data could be implemented.